# ActionMailbox ですべてのメールを特定の Mailbox に routing するには?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailbox_basics.html

^ 上記 ActionMailbox のマニュアルを読んでいました。ここで、

```
class ApplicationMailbox < ActionMailbox::Base
  routing /^save@/i     => :forwards
  routing /@replies\./i => :replies
end
```

という例示があり、この `routing` のコードによって、どの `Mailbox` クラスで処理をするのかを指定することができます。

## 質問

この routing において、「すべてのメールを特定の Mailbox に routing する」を実現したいと思いました。これを実現する `routing` のコードは何になりますか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailbox/Base.html

```
routing :all => :backstop
```

Rails Guideは「ガイド」であってAPIについての網羅的なマニュアルではないので、[APIリファレンス](https://api.rubyonrails.org/)を確認するようにしてください。